# The tab's contents are not visible when using MaterialTopTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, tabs

I intend to create a tab navigation for the profile page. The issue is that the tab's content is not visible.

```
            package.json
   "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.3",
   "react-native-pager-view": "^6.2.1",
   "react-native-svg": "^13.11.0",
   "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2"
```

---

```
       MainNavigation.js

const ProfileTabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

const Tab1 = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Text>This is Tab 1</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
const Tab2 = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Text>This is Tab 2</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const Tab3 = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Text>This is Tab 3</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export const ProfileTabNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <ProfileTabs.Navigator>
      <ProfileTabs.Screen name={'Tab1'} component={Tab1} />
      <ProfileTabs.Screen name={'Tab2'} component={Tab2} />
      <ProfileTabs.Screen name={'Tab3'} component={Tab3} />
    </ProfileTabs.Navigator>
  );
};
```

---

```
    screens->Profile->Profile.js
       <View style={{height: '100%'}}>
           <ProfileTabNavigation />
       </View>
```

---

[image: output]

https://github.com/nvacheishvili/SocialMediaApp/compare/creating-profile-page...creating-tab-navigation-for-profile-page

https://github.com/P-MBD/SocialMediaApp/commit/2c6b188cb7e1c3fa6d569d8e1b343e10834872db